# LibGDX primitive keyboard with a listener for each key

Tags: java, libgdx, listener

Trying to make a simple typing game. I've created a keyboard consisting of LibGDX scene2d TextButtons and putting them in 3 scene2d Tables (for each row of keys) and wrapping them in another Table. Here's the code so far:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

Table keyboard = new Table();
Table keysTop = new Table();
Table keysMid = new Table();
Table keysBot = new Table();

final char ascii[] = {'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P',
            'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L',
            'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M'};

// create all keys in order of the ascii[] table above
for (int index = 0; index < ascii.length; index++) {
    keys[index] = new TextButton("", skin);
    String letter = Character.toString(ascii[index]);
    keys[index].setText(letter);
    keys[index].setSkin(skin);

    // and put them in correct rows
    if (index < 10)
        keysTop.add(keys[index]).width(keySize).height(keySize + 5).pad(2);
    else if (index < 19)
        keysMid.add(keys[index]).width(keySize).height(keySize + 5).pad(2);
    else
        keysBot.add(keys[index]).width(keySize).height(keySize + 5).pad(2);
}

// add each row of keys to the keyboard Table
keyboard.add(keysTop).pad(5).expandX().fill().row();
keyboard.add(keysMid).pad(5).expandX().fill().row();
keyboard.add(keysBot).pad(5).expandX().fill().row();

stage.addActor(keyboard);
```

Now I'd like to add listeners to each key, preferably in a loop. Putting the following code at the end of the for loop:

```
keys[index].addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        System.out.println(letter);
    }
});
```

doesn't compile because of error "Variable 'letter' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final".
What's the preferred (or simplest, if preferred is difficult to implement for a beginner) solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- declare `letter` String as `final`

or

- set name of `keys[index]` TextButton by `setName(String name)` and inside changed method fetch `targetListener` name using event.

Comment: Declaring the variable as final did work. Earlier I assumed it couldn't be set as final, because final variables should not change. Am I right in thinking that in this situation it works, because I'm declaring that variable anew with each pass of the for loop?